# Laravel Query Builder: Multiple where/orWhere and precendence of and/or

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a number of search terms I want to use in an SQL query using Laravel 5.1. This is my code

```
foreach ($searchTerms as $term) {
    $query->where(function($query) use ($query, $term){
      $query->where("profiles.text", "LIKE", "%{$term}%")
            ->orWhere("protocols.text", "LIKE", "%{$term}%");
    });
  }
```

This is the SQL I get from it:

```
where 'profiles'.'text' LIKE ? or 'protocols'.'text' LIKE ? and
'profiles'.'text' LIKE ? or 'protocols'.'text' LIKE ?
```

And this is the SQL I need:

```
where ('profiles'.'text' LIKE ? or 'protocols'.'text' LIKE ?) and
('profiles'.'text' LIKE ? or 'protocols'.'text' LIKE ?)
```

What can I do to get the correct query string?

Thanks
Pida

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that in your closure you are "using" the $query. The $query is passed as an argument and you shouldn't declare it again in the use() block.

The correct code is:

```
foreach ($searchTerms as $term) {
    $query->where(function($query) use ($term){
        $query->where("profiles.text", "LIKE", "%{$term}%")
            ->orWhere("protocols.text", "LIKE", "%{$term}%");
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's an easy solution. I could have sworn I got an error when not "using" $query, but your code is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$query->where(function($query) use ($query, $term){
  $query->where("profiles.text", "LIKE", "%{$term}%")
        ->orWhere("protocols.text", "LIKE", "%{$term}%");
});
$query->where(function($query) use ($query, $term){
  $query->where("profiles.text", "LIKE", "%{$term}%")
        ->orWhere("protocols.text", "LIKE", "%{$term}%");
});
```

Comment: You repeated the whole code inside the foreach loop, is that what you wanted? When I do this, I just get more _and_  and _or_ clauses, but no parentheses to group them.